# Tizen bluetooth SPP receiving data but BT_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED on sending

Tags: android, c, bluetooth, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

i'm developing an Samsung Gear S2 using Native Tizen, i have an android app that connect as client to my Gear app using SPP, the android app have a button for sending simple text to my Gear, everything works well at here, but when i want to send data to my android using SPP from my Gear i receive a BT_ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED, here is my code summarized:

```
static void socket_connection_state_changed(int result,
        bt_socket_connection_state_e connection_state,
        bt_socket_connection_s *connection, void *user_data) {
    appdata_s *ad = (appdata_s *) user_data;

    if (result != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
                "[socket_connection_state_changed_cb] Failed. result =%d.",
                result);

        return;
    }

    if (connection_state == BT_SOCKET_CONNECTED) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Callback: Connected.");
        if (connection != NULL) {
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG,
                    "Callback: Socket of connection - %d.",
                    connection->socket_fd);
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Callback: Role of connection - %d.",
                    connection->local_role);
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG,
                    "Callback: Address of connection - %s.",
                    connection->remote_address);
            // socket_fd is used for sending data and disconnecting a device
            ad->client_socket_fd = connection->socket_fd;
        } else {
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Callback: No connection data");
        }
    } else {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Callback: Disconnected.");
        if (connection != NULL) {
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG,
                    "Callback: Socket of disconnection - %d.",
                    connection->socket_fd);
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG,
                    "Callback: Address of connection - %s.",
                    connection->remote_address);
        } else {
            dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Callback: No connection data");
        }
    }
}

static void bt_socket_data_received_callback(bt_socket_received_data_s* data,
        void* user_data) {
    if (data == NULL) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "No received data!");

        return;
    }
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Socket fd: %d", data->socket_fd);
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Data: %s", data->data);
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Size: %d", data->data_size);
}

static void start_spp_server(appdata_s *ad) {
    int server_socket_fd = -1;
    const char* my_uuid = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
    bt_error_e ret;

    ret = bt_initialize();
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "[bt_initialize] Failed.");

        return;
    } else {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "[bt_initialize] Success.");
    }

    bt_adapter_state_e adapter_state;

    // Check whether the Bluetooth adapter is enabled
    ret = bt_adapter_get_state(&adapter_state);
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "[bt_adapter_get_state] Failed");

        return;
    }
    // If the Bluetooth adapter is not enabled
    if (adapter_state == BT_ADAPTER_DISABLED) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
                "Bluetooth adapter is not enabled. You should enable Bluetooth!!");
    }

    ret = bt_socket_set_connection_state_changed_cb(
            socket_connection_state_changed, ad);
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
                "[bt_socket_set_connection_state_changed_cb] failed.");

        return;
    }

    ret = bt_socket_set_data_received_cb(bt_socket_data_received_callback,
            NULL);
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
                "[bt_socket_data_received_cb] regist to fail.");
    }

    ret = bt_socket_create_rfcomm(my_uuid, &server_socket_fd);
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "[bt_socket_create_rfcomm()] failed.");
        log_bt_errors(ret);
    }

    ret = bt_socket_listen_and_accept_rfcomm(server_socket_fd, 5);
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
                "[bt_socket_listen_and_accept_rfcomm] failed.");

        return;
    } else {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG,
                "[bt_socket_listen_and_accept_rfcomm] Succeeded. bt_socket_connection_state_changed_cb will be called.");
        // Waiting for incoming connections
        ad->server_socket_fd = server_socket_fd;
    }
}
```

Lastly i use a button for test the sending from my Gear S2, i use a callback for the button click with this code:

```
static void clicked_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Button clicked\n");
    appdata_s *ad = (appdata_s *) data;

    bt_error_e ret;
    char datatosend[] = "Sending test";

    ret = bt_socket_send_data(ad->client_socket_fd, datatosend,
            sizeof(datatosend));
    if (ret != BT_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "[bt_socket_send_data] failed.");
        log_bt_errors(ret);
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "las error code = %d", get_last_result());
    }
}
```

Using debugging i realize that my send fails with that error, i already have the bluetooth privilege setted in my manifest, what could be?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't add a privilege into your tizen-manifest.xml file.
Required privilege is:
http://tizen.org/privilege/bluetooth
and required feature:
http://tizen.org/feature/network.bluetooth

Comment: thanks i dont have that feature setted in my manifest but i keep getting access denied error.